# Castle Windsor UsingFactory xml alternative

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, castle-windsor, umbraco-ucommerce

I have an ordinary Castle Windsor component registration command:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IEntity>()
                            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new EntityFactory().CreateEntity()));
```

I need the XML configuration alternative in order to extend my UCommerce.
I've tried to register it [as described here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/factory-support-facility.md) but it doesn't work due to exception:

> Could not convert string 'Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility, Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport' to a type. Assembly was not found. Make sure it was deployed and the name was not mistyped.`

Have anyone faced equal challenge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the disclaimer at the top of your linked article:

> **Prefer `UsingFactoryMethod` over this facility**: while the facility provides programmatic API it is deprecated and its usage is discouraged and won't be discussed here. Recommended approach is to use `UsingFactoryMethod` method of fluent registration API to create components. This limits the usefulness of the facility to XML-driven and legacy scenarios.

If you still want to use XML (make sure you have a really good reason), then there are two steps you need to take:

1. **Fix the exception.**  It says it cannot find the assembly named "Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport".  This is a library that is distributed separately from Castle Windsor, and you can [get it from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.FactorySupportFacility/).  If you do have it installed, confirm that you are deploying that assembly.
2. **Create a factory object.**  The facility doen't support using an arbitrary method; you must give it a type and point it to the method to use.  So, you'd create a type like this:

   ```cs
   public class EntityFactory
   {
       public IEntity Create()
       {
           return new EntityFactory().CreateEntity();
       }
   }
   ```

   Then your XML configuration would look something like this:

   ```xml
   <components>
      <component id="entityfactory"
                 type="Your.Namespace.EntityFactory, Your.AssemblyName"/>
      <component id="entity"
                 type="Your.Namespace.IEntity, Your.AssemblyName"
                 factoryId="entityfactory" 
                 factoryCreate="Create" />
   </components>
   ```

Comment: Also if i don't include facility element in xml config it doesn't recognize factory attributes in component node and just ignores them trying to resolve my entity via constructor.